# Noisy breaker, whats the reason

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

One breaker started making a noise every time after i put it on, sometimes its immediately after switching it to on and sometimes it starts after a few seconds, and after a while the noise gets lower but consists til switched off.
Is the breaker broken? Do I have to change it?

Comment: What type of noise?

Comment: Cant describe slimier to a fly near your ears:)

Comment: What are the loads on that circuit?

Comment: Its a 15 Amp. powering about 10 flourecent fixtures.

Comment: Such noises are heard sometimes from fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

Last thing you want is a dodgy circuit breaker. I suggest that you replace it so when and if you ever have need for that breaker to protect a circuit you can depend upon it to work properly.

I got the impression from reading your posting that you are using this circuit breaker as a regular switching function. Be aware that some breakers are not intended to be used as regular switches. Others may be designed to work correctly. Please see the [accepted answer on this posting](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/does-turning-circuit-breakers-off-cause-wear) for further information.

Comment: I had to close it once and when I put it on I noticed the noise and from there it went on and off a few times, but its generally not touched.

Comment: That is good to hear. If you are hearing a buzzing or sizzling noise coming out of the circuit breaker, that is not a good thing, then I suggest replacing it. Breakers are generally not hugely expensive if you buy them from the right places.